# Which of the following is correct (or better): "Two Players" or "Two Player" as a game menu item?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

I have published a simple game for two players, whose menu contains the following:

- Single Player *(human vs. computer)*
- Two Players *(two players playing on the same device)*
- Bluetooth *(two players on two different devices)*

(Without the texts in parentheses.)

So, is it correct to say "two players" or "two player" (as in "a two-player game")? If both are correct, which one is better for this purpose?

Comment: Especially around Christmas, I should think that things like pheasant and venison work better as game menu items. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just as we can speak of a *two-man canoe*, we can speak of a *two-player* game. Best to use the hyphen, though.

Comment: If _Two-Player_ is used for Option 2, then shouldn't _Single-Player_ be used for Option 1? And, by extension, wouldn't _Single Player_ and _Two Players_ also be acceptable? (In other words, I think _consistency_ is the overriding issue here.)

Comment: @J.R.. Well, yes, of course, _Two players_ is fine if it stands alone, and doesn't modify any following noun phrase.